# Using an ID to remove a class using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I'm trying to remove the classstatic selected menu-item
using

```
 $("#slink").removeClass("static selected menu-item");
```

Thanks guys.I'm sure the Jquery script is running as i have other stuff there.
More wider snippet here:

```
<div id="zz18_TopNavigationMenuV4" class="s4-tn">
    <div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
        <ul class="root static">
            <li class="static selected">
            <a id="slink" class="static selected menu-item" href="/sites/mySite" accesskey="1">
            <span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Home</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently 
            selected</span></span></a></li>
            <ul class="dd_menu root static">
                <li class="static selected">
                <a id="slink" href="/sites/mySite/Tool/default.aspx" class="static selected menu-item">
                <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item-text">Tool</span></span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

But no luck so far.Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks good. I suspect your problem may not be that line of jQuery. I suspect either the HTML is being generated on the fly (by Javascript etc ...) or that jQuery line isn't being called. Can you post a wider example of your code.

Comment: Ensure the jQuery library is being run, can you run the IE dev toolbar and debug your code? That may lead to an issue as well

Comment: Thanks guys.I'm sure the Jquery script is running as i have other stuff there.
More wider snippet here:

Comment: I would try the removeClass with one class at a time, I'm not 100% sure that the removeClass method supports multiple classes like that.

Comment: @JamesLove [This is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485647/removing-multiple-classes-jquery)

Answer (score 6):

When using jQuery or general javascript for that matter, in a ASP.NET masterpage, it's very important that you know where to put it to make sure it takes effect.

If the javascript is placed in the header it is not always certain that the script will be read in time for the element to get affected by it. This can be solved by moving the `<script>` tag containing the javascript down beneath the HTML which is should have an effect on, like so

```
<div id="Div1"><p class='class1 class2'>Pretend this is in your masterpage<p></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#Div1 p').removeClass('class1 class2');
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.